# Replace asterisk with circumflex HEBREW_file.txt in python 2.75

Tags: python, replace, hebrew

Python 2.75 32 bit [Windows 7,64-bit, due to pygame 2.7 32-bit compatibility issues] Hebrew_File.txt (saved with utf-8) I read Hebrew in idle with this code:

```
import codecs
content= codecs.open('c:/python27/Hebrew_File.txt.', encoding='utf-8').read()
print content
```

Please help execute my task: Replace all asterisks (asterisk symbol) with circumflex (^)

a. I tried using `readlines()` for `read()` and failed.
b. I tried `content.readlines()` etc etc, using various standard code and failed.
c. Obvious failure: I went to the shell's edit tab and entered find:(asterisk symbol) and replace with:^ and all it did was highlight one asterisk in grey, but nothing further.

Thank you in advance for helping me.

PS find/replace in Word doesn't allow circumflex, so I thought I would go through python!!
PPS i've been trying different code and searching for hours -- ironically -- the time to replace manually in Word [but I refuse to abandon Python and learning to program!!]

Answer (score 0):

```
print content.replace('*', '^')
```

See the Python Standard Library: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

**EDIT:**

So it's a question about replacing *formatted* text. If Word does not let you replace * with ^, then try using LibreOffice Writer. It can open Word files quite well and usually keeps all the formatting. Replacing * with ^ in Libreoffice is as easy as one would hope: Menu Edit->Search/Replace-> enter `*` for search string and `^` for replacement. Click "Replace all" and you are done.

Comment: thank you. my tutorials taught more steps: making list, rewriting lines etc, in order to permanently save directly in the file. Here, with your solution, I copy pasted into Word and losing all other formatting (400+ page document!!). Therefore, I cannot use this method to bypass Word's exclusion of circumflex as a replacement value! How to override Word, that is the question... any ideas?

Comment: thanks again! I broke up the text into smaller pieces this morning with success, since yesterdays scare was bc larger docs (a) freeze the libreoffice or (b) take very, very long to 'import'. Why? probably bc it's a Hebrew doc file and needs converting (no pun intended:).

Comment: Oh, BTW, if using python as original question states. How to save permanently/write to the file itself?

Answer (score 0):

when using Python for txt doc
    print content.replace('*', '^')

See the Python Standard Library: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

when the Hebrew text is a formatted Word doc
(a) use Libreoffice to open the original formatted Hebrew language Word doc
(b) download Hebrew fonts for Libreoffice: http://opensiddur.org/2010/07/unicode-compliant-and-open-source-licensed-hebrew-fonts/ ...
(c) load up small files or smaller parts of large files 
(d) depending on file size it may take long or freeze